# Wait until async is completed (await)

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise, es6-promise

I am trying to get my head around with async/await

I am using https://github.com/sunnylqm/react-native-storage for my project in react-native.

I am using async storage to store few critical information such as selected user locale, I need to retrieve this value before screen is rendered to display screen based on selected locale.

I have tried implementing several helper functions, it works with callback, what I need is to return the value instead of callback and wait until the value is fetched. Below are few examples I tried.

```
// 1
_selectedLocale = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await global.storage.load({key: 'selectedLocale'});
    return value
   } catch (error) {
     console.log(value)
   }
}
var selectedLocale = _selectedLocale();

// 2
export async function _selectedLocale() {
  return storage.load({key: 'selectedLocale'});
}
var selectedLocale = _selectedLocale();
// 3
export function selectedLocale(callback) {
  storage.load({key: 'selectedLocale'}).catch(e => {
    callback(RNLanguages.language);
  }).then(function(locale) {
    callback(locale);
  });
}
```

This is not working, I am looking to

> 1. Implement a helper function to retrieve a value based on key
> 2. Wait until the value is retrieved (sync)

Can someone point me to right direction

Thanks

**UPDATE1:**

Here is how I am using the callback

```
selectedLocale(function(locale) {
  global.layoutIsRTL = 'ar' == locale;
  ReactNative.I18nManager.allowRTL(true);
  global.i18n.locale = locale
});
```

**UPDATE2:**

It seems someone has already done this, here is the reference https://github.com/sunnylqm/react-native-storage/issues/206 unfortunately I am having hard time understanding it.

Comment: `selectedLocale` always will be a promise, that's only expected. `await` doesn't stop the world, but only the current function body.

Comment: Can you please post how you got it to work with callbacks?

Comment: @Bergi updated my code, please check

Comment: I am sorry about the callback, I have not posted another function which I am using for callback, let me updated the post.

Comment: @Bergi I have added #3 in code example with callback helper.

Answer (score 0):

`async` implicitly returns a promise, so you need to await the function call as well if you want the value there:

```
var selectedLocale = await _selectedLocale();
```

but you can only do that inside of another `async` function

Comment: Aaah, to be frank, I am looking for a workaround to make it work like sync, even if that means it has to wait for execution, is there no workaround for this?

Comment: Oh I see, yes there is though I don't know much about it I've never worked with them but it sounds like you're looking for generators https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*